# How can I put a figure and text side by side in one column

Tags: tables, floats, figure-placement

I have a table in .png format and want to place it in half a column, the other half of the column will have text as in this example figure. How do I do that?

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot shows `wraptable` not `side by side table`, please have a look at `wrapfig` documentation

Comment: Use \minipage tool

Comment: As an alternative to `wrapfig`, you could have a look at https://ctan.org/pkg/wrapstuff